# jquery - assign variable inside a .html()

Tags: javascript, jquery, iframe

```
i++;   
 $("#test").html("<iframe id='i' src='arr[0]'></iframe>");
```

I want to assign the value of the array to the iframe source as shown here. This doesn't work however. How is this possible? Thanks

Comment: Does it work with other elements? I would say, you also have to reload the page inside the iframe, to see any changes.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$("#test").html("<iframe id='" + i + "' src='" + arr[0] + "'></iframe>");
```

Answer (score 2):

You need to use concatenation:

```
$("#test").html("<iframe id=\"" + i + "\" src=\"" + arr[0] + "\"></iframe>");
```

*Edited to match updated question*

Answer (score 2):

**Why your code doesn't work as expected:**

```
$("#test").html("<iframe id='i' src='arr[0]'></iframe>");
```

generates the html output:

```
<div id="test">
    <iframe id='i' src='arr[0]'></iframe>
</div>
```

Your variables are in fact outputted as literals, since you're not using any escaping/concatenation (see [this article](http://www.quirksmode.org/js/strings.html) for JS string 101).

---

**What you can do to make it work:**

While the other answers are correct, consistently using single quotes for strings makes HTML concatenation way more fun (as attribute values should usually be in double quotes):

```
i++;   
$("#test").html('<iframe id="' + i + '" src="' + arr[0] + '"></iframe>');
```

---

**What you can do to make it work even more hassle-free for you:**

It might be overkill if you need to concatenate just once. In the long run though, [this approach by @Zippoxer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format/3492815#3492815) makes your life much easier when you have to insert values into strings:

```
String.prototype.format = function() {
    var formatted = this;
    for(arg in arguments) {
        formatted = formatted.replace("{" + arg + "}", arguments[arg]);
    }
    return formatted;
};
```

Usage in your case:

```
$("#test").html('<iframe id="{0}" src="{1}"></iframe>'.format(i, arr[0]));
```

Comment: +1 I was going to go down the `.replace` route. That's how I usually do my in-string replacing. I thought it may be a bit much for the OP given their apparent skill-level. Most thorough answer though. Nice little prototype function, I think I'll steal it :)

Comment: @ElRonnoco Thanks. Be sure to check [this thread](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/610406/javascript-equivalent-to-printf-string-format) too, there's neat alternatives ;)

Comment: @ElRonnoco Also, make sure to check out [underscore.string](https://github.com/epeli/underscore.string#readme) (usable independently from the underscore lib, too).

Answer (score 1):

try this...

```
$("#test").html("<iframe id='" + i + "' src='" + arr[0] + "'></iframe>");
```

What you are doing with `$("#test").html("<iframe id='i' src='arr[0]'></iframe>");` is setting the `id` to the *literal character* `"i"` and setting the `src` to the *literal string* `"arr[0]"` rather than the *values* of these variables.